# Match string with number, unit and keyword python

Tags: python, regex

I need the following pattern: Get string from "number" followed by any char NOT letter(except 'x'), followed keyword like (oz or g) followed by other keyword like (bags, boxes, pack). Here some string as example

*40497 frozen fi ench fried potatoes organic 12/16 oz bags* --> **12/16 oz bags**

*apples 8x18x3.4 oz ( 96g ) boxes* --> **8x18x3.4 oz (96g ) boxes**

*8 red 12 green 15 - .1 oz (3g) pack* --> **15 - .1 oz (3g) pack**

I have this pattern
`(\d*\.?\d+)(\W)((|)?)(oz.).*(bag.|boxe.|pack.)` but the results are:

**16 oz bags**

**3.4 oz (96g ) boxes**

**.1 oz (3g) pack**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this part `(\d*\.?\d+)` with `[\d\.][\d\.x\-\s\/]+`

`[\d\.]`: to make sure that the matching result starts with a digit or a dot (one character)

`[\d\.x\-\s\/]+`: then the remaining group of characters (one or more) before `oz` keyword could be any of:

- digit
- dot
- "x" character
- "-" character
- space
- slash

Comment: Greattt!!! It took me hours trying to find the pattern. Thanks @Yasser Mohsen